# Error in eclipse : Import javax.sound.sampled.* cannot be resolved

Tags: eclipse, java

I am trying to run a project in which a file uses the line

```
import javax.sound.sampled.* ;
```

When I try to compile it in Eclipse (running on Ubuntu) it shows the error that this line cannot be resolved. Can anyone help me out how to install this package.

Comment: which version of java you are running ? its there for sure from 1.4 and later

Comment: [`javax.sound.sampled`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/package-summary.html) should be part of the standard JDK...

Comment: yes i have openJDK Runtime Environment (1.6.0) installed but it's not working whilst other imports are showing no error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the [`openjdk-6-jdk`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=openjdk-6-jdk)/[`default-jdk`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=default-jdk) (karmic and newer) or [`sun-java6-jdk`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=sun-java6-jdk) (karmic and older) package installed.  If it's not installed, it should show up in the Package Manager app, or through the aptitude command-line program (`aptitude install openjdk-6-jdk`)

`default-jdk` is a newish meta-package that should install the recommended JDK for your system, but this is likely always going to be openjdk-6-jdk, as it's the GPLv2 version of Sun's JDK.

Comment: I have openJDK Runtime Environment 1.6.60 installed

Comment: @Tasbeer: The Runtime Environment isn't enough, you also need the Development Kit.  Granted, they apparently changed the package name for newer releases.  I've updated my answer with the newer package name.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

•Go to Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path
•Select Libraries tab
•Select the JRE entry
•Workspace Default jre -> Finish